# Mac vs. Windows: Reading environment variable in Ant build files

Tags: java, ant

I've got a project that references environment variables in the Ant build file.

```
<property environment="env" />
<!-- RESOLVE -->
<target name="{target}">
    <if>
        <isset property="env.MY_HOME"/>
        <then>
            <property name="my.home" value="${env.MY_HOME}"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="my.home" value="${env.USERPROFILE}/me"/>
        </else>
    </if>   
</target>
```

Other developers on Windows machines don't even have to define the `env.IVY_HOME` or `env.USERPROFILE` variables. But I, as a Mac user, am getting the following error during the build process:

```
settings file does not exist
```

Now, I have successfully added and echoed `IVY_HOME` and even `USERPROFILE` in my `.bash_profile` file but I still get that same error.

---

UPDATE: Even the environment variables in my *pom.xml* aren't being read:

```
<systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/myJarFile.jar</systemPath>
```

If I make changes in my *build.xml* file even my repo doesn't pick up that the file has been changed. Why would that be? I'm guessing ANT properties are immutable.

I have to hardcode the path to get it to work:

```
<systemPath>{pathToMyJar}</systemPath>
```

Why would me, as a Mac user, run into this issue whereas Windows users don't even have to set the environment variables and can still build fine?

---

UPDATE:
It works for my Windows colleagues because there is a default USERPROFILE environment variable. But, on a Mac, the equivalent is `$HOME`. How can I fix that? I have tried `export USERPROFILE=$HOME` in my `.profile` and `.bash_profile` files but it's still trying to read `env.USERPROFILE`.

Here it is in `mybuild.xml` (I guess another ant file that is triggered for local development from `build.xml`):

```
<target name="init-my-stuff">
    <if>
        <isset property="env.MY_HOME"/>
        <then>
            <property name="my.home" value="${env.MY_HOME}"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="my.home" value="${env.USERPROFILE}/me"/>
        </else>
    </if>   

</target>
```

Comment: To access the environment using the env prefix your build needs to include `<property environment="env" />` somewhere. Maybe that is, for some reason, only run for Windows users of your buildfile.

Comment: I do have it; sorry, I'll update the ticket.

Comment: Might depend how Ant is run - .bashrc versus .bash-profile differences if you see what I mean?

Comment: Did you export your IVY_HOME variable ? add an <echoproperties> to see which properties you actually have https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html .

Comment: Yes, it outputs this: [echo] ivy.home is ${env.USERPROFILE}/ivy

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Your most recent edit here appears to be incomplete (not all `IVY_HOME` are changed). You appear to be at least partially removing identifying content from the post. In general, we don't strenuously object to that, but you need to *carefully* edit such that you leave a viable question which isn't of lower quality for future users and the edit need to not invalidate answers or make the answers not fit as well with the question. Relatively minor things like changing `IVY_HOME` to `MY_HOME` are OK, but you should propose edits to any answers which use that string so they use the new value. (cont)

Comment: (cont) However, that does *not* mean that you should make sweeping changes to answers (or questions, for that matter). Our priority is that questions and answers are not reduced in quality, that people's impression of the answers work isn't degraded (e.g. the "fit" with the question), and the Q&A remains helpful to future visitors, through multiple aspects (e.g. including being easy to search for using keywords, continuing to cover the same issues, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_java/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64542959) works on my Mac. The `build.xml` is similar to the one in your question. I'm using Ant 1.9.6, Ivy 2.5.0, and Ant Contrib 1.0b3.

To test, I'm using the following `run.sh` in Bash. It is fairly basic, so it will be a useful test to see if it works for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset IVY_HOME
unset USERPROFILE

# try either of these:
# export IVY_HOME=~/tools/apache-ivy/apache-ivy-2.5.0
export USERPROFILE=~/tools/apache-ivy/apache-ivy-2.5.0

ant init-ivy
```

Of course, you will have to change the paths to be specific for your machine. By commenting out `IVY_HOME` or `USERPROFILE` as appropriate, Ant will use the `<then>` or `<else>` branch as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response but, for some reason, even though I'm setting the environment variables correctly it still looks for env.USERPROFILE. I've updated the original post with the target that checks for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ant properties are immutable. Once set they cannot be changed anymore. There are ways around this - you can set a variable only for within a single target using the `<local>` task. for example, or use macros, but that doesn't appear to be relevant for your question, so let's get to the mystery of the missing `env.IVY_HOME` variable.

On linux/mac in particular, every process gets a brand new fresh 'environment' (in java terms, basically a `Map<String, String>`), which may be initialized to hold a bunch of extra values if the spawning process decides it wants to do that.

**The key point is, if your bash tells you IVY_HOME exists, that does not imply your ant process will see that!**

That's what `export` is for; if you set a property as with `IVY_HOME=....` then your shell will not copy that one over to any newly spawned processes. If you stick export in front, it should. One easy enough test is to spawn a bash from within your ant and ask it to print all properties:

```
<project name="test" default="test">
  <target name="test">
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
      <arg value="-c" />
      <arg value="set" />
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Instructions: Save above to `build.xml` in a new dir, then run `ant`.**

run the above and I bet that IVY_HOME, USERPROFILE etc aren't in the list in the first place, which suggests that you did not 'set' these properties in the first place. Either you did not export them, or, you're running into a different problem, the concept of 'interactive variables' and 'non-interactive variables'. This isn't baked into the sysenv system, but into most linux/mac setups of shells: There are a whole bunch of shell scripts that are read in when a new shell is started. THere's `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `etc/bash_profile`, `/etc_profile`, sometimes an `/etc/profile.d` dir with many scripts, and more.

Which ones *actually* get invoked when you fire up a shell depends on what shell you're firing up and whether it is 'interactive' or not. It is quite possible you've added `export IVY_HOME=....` to a file that isn't even being read in.

Environment variables you want globally available should probably go in `~/.profile`.

You can always tell bash to specifically pass some env vars to your process. Try this:

```
FOO=hello ant
```

in the same dir as the *invoke bash -c set as a test* script above. That's one way you can force the issue; by running `IVY_HOME=/path/to JAVAHOME=/path/to ant build` or whatnot (any equals-sign-separated string put in front of a command tells bash to put that key/value pair into the hashmap it is making for that process).

If that last one still doesn't result in your ant script picking up `env.IVY_HOME`, then something really weird is going on, and it's time to paste the full script, I think.

Comment: thank you for the very thorough response. i can't run the test because i don't have ant installed. but i think i have an idea as to why it works for my windows colleagues and not me, because Windows has a default USERPROFILE environment variable. But the newbuild.xml file (triggered some how by build.xml) is still trying to read env.USERPROFILE and I don't know why.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and though I'm still struggling with this, your response helped me get closer to the source of the problem. So I will award you the bounty.